# Event after selecting item from checkbox multiple select list

Tags: jquery, html

I have to display second select list if particular item is selected in first list.

I have.. First list as following

```
      <select id="mail_list" name="survey_mail_to[]" multiple="multiple" >
         <option value="bu_head">BU Head</option>
         <option value="all_employee">All Employee</option>                                     
     </select>
```

Second list..

```
    <select id="bu_list" name="bu_emp[]" multiple="multiple" >
         <option value="1">OBU</option>
         <option value="2">PBU</option>                                     
     </select>
```

If `all_employee` is selected in first list i have ti display second list.
i am using jquery 'multiselect' plugin for checkbox in lists.

I tried this..

```
$( "#mail_list" ).change(function(e) {
e.preventDefault(); 
var mailop = document.getElementById("mail_list").value;
    if(mailop=='all_employee')
    {
        $("#bu_list").show();
    }  
});
```

it is not working. any idea please

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/j5DUE/. Check your console for errors. Also, your mix of native js and jQuery is a little odd. You can change `document.getElementById("mail_list").value` to just `this.value`

Comment: yes. i am getting event.returnValue is deprecated error

Answer (score 1):

Since you have multiple select enabled, try

```
$("#mail_list").change(function (e) {
    $("#bu_list").toggle($('#mail_list option[value="all_employee"]').is(':selected'));
});
```

Also, [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/change) is not cancelable.

Comment: I tried this but getting 'event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.' this error